# Are $\int y dx$ and $\int f(x) dx$ the same?

Tags: integration

Let $y = f(x)$ and consider the following expressions

1. $\displaystyle \int {y dx}$
2. $\displaystyle \int {f(x) dx}$
3. $\displaystyle \int_a^b {y dx}$
4. $\displaystyle \int_a^b {f(x) dx}$

> Is it correct to say that expressions 1. and 2. are the same (up to some constant of integration), because here $x$ is not a dummy variable; **expressions 3. and 4. are different, because there $x$ is a dummy variable?**

---

Elaboration: In particular, if we use a different dummy variable in 3., say $w$, we get

5. $\displaystyle \int_a^b {y dw}$

It seems to me there are two distinct possibilities.

**EITHER** 5. is different from 3., which means there exist definite integrals in which the variable of integration is not a dummy variable.

**OR** 5. is same as 3. Since $y$ is not a function of $w$, then it follows that 3. is different from 4.

I think the second possibility is correct. Please confirm or deny, thanks.

Comment: 1 and 2 are the same. 3 and 4 are the same. It’s not clear what you mean by exists outside the integral. dx tells you what variable you are integrating with respect to.

Comment: @AndrewZhang I'm thinking the answer to 3 is $y(b - a)$, due to reasons outlined in my edit.

Comment: I think your edit shows that you may need to reread some of the definitions and write out all parts of the equations until you're more comfortable. As you point out, the variable $w$ is a "dummy" variable. There is a difference between
$$ \int_a^b y(x) \ dw = (b-a) y(x)  $$
and
$$\int_a^b y(w) \ dw.$$
When the argument is omitted for $y = f(x)$ it is generally implied that your integration is being done with respect to the argument. The former is unusual.